# Splitting a file into a list then into separate parts - Python

Tags: python

I am currently trying to split a file into a list of IPs, how would i make it run until the end of the file and then stop when it reaches the end. It currently reads the first lines splits it and stops.

```
with open('log1.txt') as logFile: 
  for line in logFile:
    i = i+1
    content_list = line.split("-")
    #ipList[i] = content_list[1] # I want it to be split into this list
    break
print(content_list[1])
```

Here is also an example of what my list looks like

```
172.16.121.64 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:46:19] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.64 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:46:23] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.64 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:46:27] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.35 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:46:28] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.240 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:46:31] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
```

Comment: Why that break statement? that's the reason why you can't reach the end of the file since it ends the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split the line at space and take element at index 0. You can do evevrything in list comprehension

```
with open('log1.txt') as logFile: 
    ips = [line.split()[0] for line in logFile]
print(ips)
```

If you plan to manipulate IPs further, look at [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) from Standard Library.

Comment: I just need to sort them and find out the most frequent one now

Comment: Look at [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its [most_common()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.